# Rails headless browser testing without installing browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium

We're doing some testing in Rails using a headless browser for our feature tests using RSpec and the web drivers gem: https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers to get the Chrome driver.

However we've had some issues whereby some developers don't have Chrome installed (and don't intend to) and also we have our app running on a Jenkins pipeline and we want to avoid having to install Chrome on the server for the tests...

Is it possible to run a headless browser without installing the actual browser as well as a hard dependancy on the system that the tests run on?

I've read conflicting articles that state headless allows you to still do your testing either when the system doesn't have the browser installed... but at the same time the documentation for Chrome and Firefox state the browser also needs to be installed when using their drivers.

https://github.com/rubycdp/cuprite I also came across this which bypasses the need for WebDriver etc... but still seems to have a hard dependancy on having Chrome installed on the system the tests run on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a browser:

- Chrome: `chromedriver`
- Firefox: `geckodriver`
- Edge: `edgedriver`
- Internet Explorer: `iedriver`

See https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers